# Change of voice within a sentence

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, passive-voice

I am currently proof-reading a technical manual and am coming across numerous instances of sentence structure which I believe to be incorrect. Here's an example:

> After filling in a custom field, *this* will add a new field to the
>   Add Person screen...

My problem is with the use of the word "this" after the first phrase. I re-worded to say,

> After filling in a custom field, a new field will be added...

I think this is a case of active vs. passive voice. Am I right to note the first statement as incorrect grammar?

Comment: Yes you are correct that the first statement is incorrect.  I'd probably correct it to: "Filling in a custom field adds a new field to the Add Person screen..." or "A new field can be added to the Add Person screen by [simply] filling in one of the empty custom entry fields on the page." or similar.

Comment: *When filling in a field, a new field will be added . . . * is also formally incorrect; a leading participle clause without a subject is deemed to take the subject of the following main clause as its subject, and I cannot believe you mean that the new field fills in the custom field.

Comment: What Jim and Stoney said but additionally, depending on who the audience is for the manual, the back-end database people or the front-facing end-user, might better determine how you state that sentence.  "Use a custom field to add additional information to the "Add Person" screen." vs. "Custom fields can be used to augment the data captured in the "Add Person" screen."

Comment: I mis-typed my correction. Add the word "After" in place of "When" at the first of the sentence.

Comment: "By filling in a custom field you add a new field to the Add Person screen . . .." Or, "By filling in a custom field you are adding [or, you'll be adding] a new field to the Add Person screen . . .."

Answer (score 1):

> "After filling in a custom field, a new field will be added..."

There are two ways I would address this.

First, if I want to stress the filling of the custom field as a cause in a cause/reaction, I would use the word, "Once," instead of the word "After."

> "Once a custom field is filled, a new field will be added..."

But, I would usually rather stress the result of the cause/reaction formula.

> "A new field will be added once a custom field is filled."

My reason for this is that I assume the cause, filling the custom field, is going to be done anyway, and the thing that the reader needs to be aware of is the result.

Answer (score 0):

Comments seem to provide the answer, so I'm summarizing them so this question can be marked as answered.

The first sentence is incorrect because a leading participle clause without a subject is deemed to take the subject of the following main clause as its subject.  The second sentence seems to be well worded and clear.  Please consider the target audience to determine if the sentence could be clarified further.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice it and I deleted my comment. But the comment is suggesting better sentences than using the passive voice (second example). I don't think the second sentence seems to be well worded.

Comment: I disagree with you about the second sentence: "*After* filling in a custom field, a new field will be added...".  The new field is added *as a result of* filling in a custom field. "After" implies a subsequent, separate event.

Comment: To be honest, there is none of Me in my answer, I just did my best to compile the comments above into an answer.  If you can propose a better answer, please do so.

Answer (score 0):

The primary problem with both sentences is a **dangling modifier**. A dangling modifier is a grammatical phrase that isn't directly followed by the noun it modifies.

In this case, the participial phrase

> filling in a custom field

should be followed by the noun it modifies - i.e. the subject that filled in the field.

In the first example,

> this will add a new field to the Add Person screen.

you are correct that the word "this" is ambiguous and doesn't really indicate who is being modified.

But, as others have commented,

> a new field will be added.

is also incorrect, because the the leading participle does not modify "a new field." That is, it is not the "new field" that filled in the custom field.

So, the problem is not the active vs. passive voice; rather, it's a missing/ambiguous subject. You need to answer the question, who is filling in the new field (e.g. you, the programmer, etcetera). Simply replace "this" with that subject, and your dangling modifier will be corrected.

Sources: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_modifier